# indicator for the modified code in cell at Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How can i configure to indicate the cell yet to run after the code has modified from the previous run?

Situation when lower cells depends on the upper cell value. 
If I have modified code at upper cells and forgot to run. Then, run the code in the lower cell. Therefore, lower cells took the old value from the upper cells because forgotten or unnoticeably the code has modified without re-run the upper cell.

Is the jupyter has such feature or where to configure?

Comment: I just happened upon this question while looking for a way to have a last-run timestamp for each cell. I love the idea of a mark to show it had been modified. I've long wanted a way to tell whether the cell had been run in the current kernel, since the `In […]` execution counter persists across kernels.